# Android PDF reader component

Tags: android, pdf, components, viewer

For an Android application we must add a PDF viewer. We can't use the PDF reader install on the platform because we want to make some animations for page switch and we want that the PDF reading is integrate correctly in our application.

So I search a component who make that in lgpl or a component that we can buy to integrate in our API and without loose a lot of time.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF reading on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143280/pdf-reading-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar need few days back and I went for iText PDF for Android. I used that to generate PDF. It also capable to read PDF.

Grab from link http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextpdfandroid/files/

Comment: can please provide me doc how to use it?

Comment: Sorry guys, that link is broken now but it was the link I used. Anyways you may go for this link http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/ and more appropriately search for itext +Android on Google.

Comment: Both above link are not working, if somebody have correct link please send me

Comment: also I am creating a app which has pdf in app, I need to view it vertical instead of horizonal