# invoking of pdf reader in android application

Tags: android

how to implement pdf reader in my application using existing code of pdf readers. please help me as soon as possible!!

We have a need to embed PDF reader in one of our custom built Android  application from local directory (Sdcard).

Comment: would you mind sharing what you have tried so far?

Comment: search in SO using keywords "[android] launch pdf reader" ... this question has been answered many times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916108/android-open-a-pdf-from-my-app-using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143280/pdf-reading-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Follow a PdfUtils class that I'm used to use to show PDF documents in my android applications.

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Environment;

 public class PdfUtils {

    static public boolean isAnyPdfReaderAvailable(Context context) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("path-to-document"));
         intent.setType("application/pdf");
         PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
         List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
         if (activities.size() > 0)
            return true;
         else
            return false;
    }

     static public void loadPdfInReader(Context context, String doc) throws ActivityNotFoundException, Exception {
        try {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
             File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + doc);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
             context.startActivity(intent);
         } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {
            activityNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
             throw activityNotFoundException;
         } catch (Exception otherException) {
            otherException.printStackTrace();
             throw otherException;
         }
     }

 }
```